# JQuery insertAfter() Method only works once when inserting a Chart.js chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, chart.js

So what I'm trying to do is insert graphs within the same div wrapper as my my ordered lists. This works perfectly as a plain `<canvas>` element, but once I make it a Chart using Chart.js for some reason it only will be inserted once after the specified element, instead of everytime.

```
<div id="box3">
                <script>
                    $("<div class='content-wrapper'>").insertBefore("ol");
                    $( "</div>" ).insertBefore( "ol" );
                    $("<canvas id='mychart'></canvas>").insertAfter("h2");
                </script>
                <script>
                    let myChart = document.getElementById('mychart').getContext('2d');

                    let habitChart = new Chart(myChart, {
                        type:'line', // bar, horizontalBar, pie, line, doughnut, radar, polarArea
                        data:{
                            labels:['item 1','item 2','item 3','item 4','item 5'],
                            datasets:[{
                                data:[34242,3242,234,234343,234342,]
                            }]
                        },
                        options:{
                            responsive: false
                        }
                    });

                </script>
            </div>
```

Comment: Ids have to be **unique**

Comment: that's true, @Andreas, but it's not the reason his thing isn't working. https://jsfiddle.net/szeq01vj/

Comment: @TKol, it **is** the reason. Your fiddle does not ever *select* an element by id.

Comment: @trincot no it's not. I've made it work using ids.

Comment: Oh, I thought you came here with a question saying it didn't work. Must be my misunderstanding. So you are saying you don't have an issue anymore?

Comment: @trincot sorry, of course. It's real hard to see what this guy wants to happen, I didn't even catch that.

Comment: @TKoL As trincot already said: the id is the problem. `document.getElementById` will always return the first element with the given id. The `<canvas>`es are added to the DOM, but the chart is always added to the first one.

Comment: @trincot I'm sorry, my mistake,  you're defininitely correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this line you select the `canvas` by its `id`:

```
let myChart = document.getElementById('mychart').getContext('2d');
```

But the second time it will not find the *second* `canvas`, but the first, because an `id` is assumed to be unique.

To solve this, do not use `id`, nor `getElementById`. Instead capture the `canvas` object at the moment it is inserted in the document, and reference that directly:

```
    let $canvas = $("<canvas id='mychart'></canvas>").insertAfter("h2");
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    let myChart = $canvas.get(0).getContext('2d');
//                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I'm just confused as to what ```.get(0)``` is doing in this scenario

Comment: `get(0)` gets the DOM element out of a jQuery object. jQuery works with a kind of wrapper around one or more DOM objects, which allows a lot of interesting manipulations on them, but `getContext` is a method on the core DOM object, so you must kind of "unpack" the jQuery object to get to that DOM object before applying the method to it.

Comment: Thank you so much for  the help